# Maximize browser window in LeanFT

Tags: java, google-chrome, leanft

I am looking for some solution, like this in Selenium WebDriver:

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();options.addArgument("--start-maximized");
```

So browser window should be maximized when test is executed.

I found a profile based solution for this problem, but it opens a lot of tabs, which is maybe caused by escape characters.

```
@Test
    public void chromeWithProfileLaunch() throws Exception {
        String profileDir = "--user-data-dir=\"c:\\Temp\\profile1\""; //should be different folder every time
        String leanftChromeExtension = "--load-extension=C:\\Program Files (x86)\\HPE\\LeanFT\\Installations\\Chrome\\Extension"; //to load the LeanFT extension
        String homePage = "www.google.com"; //the homepage to start with

        new ProcessBuilder("C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\chrome.exe", profileDir, leanftChromeExtension, homePage)
            .start();

        Thread.sleep(2000); //wait for Chrome process to load

        Browser openedBrowser = BrowserFactory.attach(new BrowserDescription.Builder().title("Google").type(BrowserType.CHROME).build());

        Verify.areEqual(homePage, openedBrowser.getURL());
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know about maximized but LeanFT supports putting the browser in [`fullScreen` mode](https://admhelp.microfocus.com/leanft/en/12.53/JavaSDKReference/com/hp/lft/sdk/web/Browser.html#fullScreen()).

Answer (score 1):

LeanFT doesn't support `maximize()` out of the box **yet**.

However, you could use `sendKeys()` method. 
I'm not entirely sure if you can to it on the `browser` instance directly, or you need to `getPage()` first, but you can definitelly send `Super` key (win key) + `↑` as specified [here](https://help.gnome.org/users/gnome-help/stable/shell-windows-maximize.html.en). `↓` for restoring back to the initial state.

Here's an example [using `sendKeys` with Java SDK](https://admhelp.microfocus.com/leanft/en/14.03/HelpCenter/Content/CodeSamples_Java/codeex_Web.htm?Highlight=sendKeys) if you need it.

Comment: As I see `getPage()` doesn't have `sendKeys()` method.

Comment: @plaidshirt I apologize, you are correct. `sendKeys` is supported only on `EditField` interface. Do you have such an element on a page? If not you could inject one temporarily, but it would be a hacky solution and I'm not 100% sure it'll work

Comment: Yes and sendKeys() is instable too, I used it earlier. Than maybe an AutoIT script could be a solution, but it is not so lightweight solution.